# Pass props not a child component (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs

How pass props to component which is not a child component

```
//I want pass mainData to Component2
let mainData = [
  {
      text_plain: "Text1",
  },
  {
      text_plain: "Text2",
  },
];

function Component1 (props) {
 return (
   <div>
     <Link to={`Component2 url`}>
   </div>
 )
}
```

I don't want to make the Сomponent2 a child, because i don't want rendering Component2 in Component1. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Read about https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html. It's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

For this you are going to want a global state management system. There are many out there, but I prefer context.

Context is a react hook and the documentation can be found here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext